# How To Get Label Text Value On CheckChange Event

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, event-handling

I am trying to get a label's text on a checkbox's `CheckChange` event. My checkbox change event handler is:

```
protected void chk_selector_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

and my label is:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <a href="javascript:openPopup('Ds_ProjectDetails.aspx?mode=1&cid=<%# Eval("CompanyID") %>&prj=<%#Eval("ProjectID")%>' )">
                            <%--<%#Eval("Title")%>--%>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>'></asp:Label></a>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ControlStyle Width="400px" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

I get the ID when the checkbox `CheckChange` event is called:

```
 CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;        
 GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)chk.Parent.Parent;
 bool flag = chk.Checked;
 string EntryID = Convert.ToString(gvProjects.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value);
 con.Update_inv_Proj_Flag(EntryID, flag);
```

Comment: Reason for down voting :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender; 
GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)chk.Parent.Parent;
var lbl = (Label) gr.FindControl("lblTitle");  
if(lbl !=null)
{          
    var lblText = lbl.Text;
}
```